# PostgreSQL: best way to call the same function multiple times in one query?

Tags: performance, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, what is the best way to call the same function multiple times in the same query?

Example:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       sum_one(a.id) AS "Sum_one",
       sum_two(a.id) AS "Sum_two",
       (sum_one(a.id )+sum_two(a.id)) AS "Sum_three"
  FROM a
```

Where `sum_one()` and `sum_two()` are functions. I repeat the call of `sum_one()` and `sum_two()`. This will slow down queries in large databases.

I want to avoid the following statement.

```
(sum_one(a.id )+sum_two(a.id)) AS "Sum_three"
```

How can I do it that in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3):

You should set your function volatility to `Stable`.

[More about function volatility](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunc(prm_MyParam integer)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  {...}

END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    "Sum_one",
    "Sum_two",
    ("Sum_one" + "Sum_two") AS "Sum_three"
FROM (
    SELECT sum_one("A"."id") AS "Sum_one", sum_two("A"."id") AS "Sum_two" FROM A
)
```